# Windows 7 will not boot after installing ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-7

My HP desktop will not boot Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  I ran Boot Repair and it said it was successful but still it just boots Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  I also updated grub as well and still the same issue. Here is the Boot Repair address I got after trying to fix the issue: [http://paste.ubuntu.com/6322631/](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6322631).

Answer (score 0):

Turn off **UEFI** mode in bios.And then try `boot-repair`.